# Moment is undefined when bundled

Tags: javascript, webpack, momentjs, bundle

I'm trying to bundle moment.js but it keeps returning undefined after it's bundled:

My webpack

```
var path = require("path");
var webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
    entry: {
        frb: "./src/app/loader.js"
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/lib"),
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                query: {
                    presets: [
                        [
                            "@babel/preset-env",
                            {
                                targets: {
                                    chrome: "58",
                                    ie: "9"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        // Ignore all locale files of moment.js
        new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            moment: "moment"
        })
    ]
};
```

My loader.js just cotains:

`require("moment")`

Comment: Have you looked at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42004016/import-moment-js-in-js-file-in-webpack)?

Comment: I tried but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Why are you using a `require("moment")` in `loader.js` but also using `webpack.IgnorePlugin` and `webpack.ProvidePlugin` at the same time? That all seems contradictory. Try removing both plugins and simply do `const moment = require("moment")` in your code?

Comment: Because I don't know what I'm doing and instructions are sparse.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the entire plugins section from your webpack config and see if it works.
There are few issues/docs I read and that last part is just trying to import minimal code from moment and should be used with specific moment version.

Take a look at following links.
https://webpack.js.org/plugins/ignore-plugin/
https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/2373

Another thing I would suggest is try requiring some other module in your loader.js apart from moment and see if that is part of your bundle. Just to verify this problem is with just moment or all modules. If it occurs for all modules then there is also something else which is incorrect in config.